# Setting App pool identity of an ASP.NET App deployed via AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can you set the App pool identity of an ASP.NET application deployed via AWS Elastic Beanstalk? I cant see any configuration options in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html). The closest thing i have found is [.edextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html#windows-commands), but it states the commands are run before the app is deployed, which would probably overwrite any specific config I had set by command?